# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the text of a textbox when a checkbox is checked and i get this error on the console

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'

Its probably something very simple, but i cant figure this out

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain" id="pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain">

<input id="pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:icConvMatchFieldInLeadForAccount" type="text" value="Company" size="20" name="pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:icConvMatchFieldInLeadForAccount" maxlength="80">
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

   $('#pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain').change(function() {
       if ('#pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain').is(':checked')) {
         $('#pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:icConvMatchFieldInLead').val('Website_Domain__c');
       }
       else{
         $('#pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:icConvMatchFieldInLead').val('Company');
       }
    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k74891hy/2/)

Comment: Once you corrected the typo, you will probably have problems with the colons in the identifiers as those are used for pseudo classes in selectors. See [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the missing `$(` on your `if` condition, you're using characters (colons) in your `id` that aren't valid for a simple id selector in CSS (e.g., the `#xxx` type); [details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). jQuery *may* let you get away with it (although I'd be fairly surprised), but it's invalid, and so could change in any dot release.

You can use an attribute selector instead:

```
$("[id=pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain]")...
```

...or escape all those colons.

Also, you can use `this.checked` in the `change` handler, and the conditional operator rather than `if/else`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id="pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain"]').change(function() {
        $('[id="pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:icConvMatchFieldInLead"]').val(
            this.checked ? 'Website_Domain__c' : 'Company'
        );
    });
});
```

Live copy:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id="pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain"]').change(function() {
        $('[id="pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:icConvMatchFieldInLead"]').val(
            this.checked ? 'Website_Domain__c' : 'Company'
        );
    });
});
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain"> The checkbox
</label>
<br>
The input: <input type="text" id="pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:icConvMatchFieldInLead">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I dont have control over the way the ids come through so using the attribute is the best bet .. Thanks once again..learning new things :)

Comment: : Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id=pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain] .I am getting a syntax error while using the .change handler. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Prady: Sorry, turns out we need quotes around the attribute value, because we need a CSS *string*, not *identifier*, since colons are invalid in identifiers -- the whole reason we're using the `id` selector! (Doh!) See update and live version above.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues in your code:

1) You need to escape the special characters while building the selector

2) You are missing jquery selector in if condition.

also you can narrow down the code to use `$(this)` to use context of currently clicked object

```
 $('[id="pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain"]').change(function() {
   if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
     $(this).next().val('Website_Domain__c');
   }
   else{
    $(this).next().val('Company');
   }
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4km9gmoc/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
if ('#pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain').is(':checked'))
```

Is your problem, it should be

```
if ($('#pgManageCS:frmManageCS:pbSettings:pbsDupeMatch:pbsiDupeMatch:chkwebsiteDomain').is(':checked'))
```

I recommend you use a linter like [JSHint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint)